# How to convert float to int - Type Casting To String Format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, floating-point, int, type-conversion

I want to type conversion of following.

My C# code is.

```
float percentage = (present/total) * 100;
lblPercentage.Text += String.Format("{0:0.00}", (float)present / (float)total);
```

It gives output like: `0.71` but I want output something like: `71`

Comment: integers are for storing whole numbers, `0.71` is not a whole number, you could round to the nearest using `Math.Round` but that would just give you `1`

Comment: I don't get it. You have just calculated the value needed. Why don't you use it in you string.format?

Comment: You already have percentage! `lblPercentage.Text = percentage.ToString();`

Comment: Do you want the % symbol in the output as well? Have a look at the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) documentation.

Comment: thanks for your replies.....i got my answer as V4Vendetta said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `{0:p}` as the format then itt would display properly with the `%` sign